# Online Yemenite Siddur

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, prayer-book

Does anyone know where to find a Baladi or Dor Dai Tiklal? I have seen a Siddur haRasha"sh, a Shami tiklal however, I would like to see the pre-Lurianic nusach of Teiman.

Comment: http://dordeah.com/siddur.zip

This is a siddur based on the Rambam and R' Saadia Gaon. So it's basically Yemenite without some of the Yemenite specific liturgy. :DDDD

Comment: i didnt download that to see if its the one i think it is, but dordeah.com is not real teimoni dor doi3eem. if you have an i device you can download tiklal for free. but that is a modern tiklal which adds modern things. and this goes for most baladi siddurim, even seeya7 yarusholayeem by mori qafi7. mori qafi7 explains why he did that and says that one should use his sefar ahavo for the proper nosa7. http://markov.podval.org/Rambam_Siddur.pdf but this is a good rambam siddur for free. or use machon mamre sefar ahavo.

Comment: This link does not work: http://markov.podval.org/Rambam_Siddur.pdf   Do you know of a better link?

Comment: @YehudaW https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a9631iptz5p03w/Siddur%20Masoroth%20Mosha.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov - Now _that link_ doesn't work.

Comment: @ezra https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlLVRibjBtY2VjNDQ

Comment: @rosenjcb - Do not use anything for Dor Deah. http://www.torathmoshe.com/2012/07/our-total-non-affiliation-with-dor-deah/ Obviously I am speaking of the Dor Deah of "Rabbi" Asher Meza, not the authentic [Temani group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dor_Daim) under the same name under [Rabbi Yihyah Qafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi%E1%B8%A5yah_Qafi%E1%B8%A5) from the early 20th Century.

Comment: @ezra, you might want to link one of the questions asked about Asher Meza ר"ל. He is well-known as a ba'al machlokes and otherwise problematic individual on this site.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84449/asher-mezas-siddur-kosher-or-not

Comment: @ezra, there are a few others besides. You don't need to tag me though, since I wrote the OP

Comment: Sorry it's habit and it shows others who I'm talking to in a sea of comments.