# Asher Meza's siddur, kosher or not?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, rambam, prayer-book, yemenite-temani

it's me again, I am soon going to a travel after Tisha B'av and I am searching for a concise siddur so I can daven fastly. I found a really concise siddur called "ways of torah" made by a controversial Rabbi called Asher Meza. Is that siddur really kosher? The Rav claims he got inspiration from Rambam's and Saadiah gaon's siddur but is that true? If it's not kosher how can I get a nice concise siddur, I searched for Mesorat Moyshe, found it's download but the link is screwed. Pls answer thanks.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130813131710AABGDZ2 Probably closer to a nut than a rabbi

Comment: Related: http://www.torathmoshe.com/2012/07/our-total-non-affiliation-with-dor-deah/

Comment: Specifically for Tish'a B'Av, I assume that the term "daven fastly" means that you don't want to do all the *Kinot*. You don't need to do all of them. As a matter of fact, you don't need to do any of them. As far as the other sections of the morning prayers, they are pretty much the same as any weekday. For that matter, they are noticeably shorter than most weekdays.

Comment: I would stay far away from anything related to "Rabbi" Asher Meza.

Comment: By the way, look what happens when you search "siddur ways of torah": https://www.google.com/search?q=siddur+ways+of+torah&oq=siddur+ways+of+torah&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1.4428.5207.0.5451.7.7.0.0.0.0.127.624.5j2.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.6.522...0i8i7i30k1.D7lh4SeBUPE Look at the first result. I don't think you should be using this siddur at all, for any reason.

Comment: oh ****, how could I find a compact siddur for my travel, I found the link to Mesorat Moshe, but the link is broken :( help.

Comment: @DanF the question involves traveling **after** tish'a b'av and a request for a compact sidur to use while traveling (on a regular day).

Comment: http://bejewish.org/tr3.pdf @ezra interestingly enough, the messy-antics that approve of the sidur, are shown in their complete paganism at the site that they pretend has the sidur that they like.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen that this "rav" Asher Meza has no good reputation and that the siddur above is used by the minim messianics.